# Share file system between VMWare Linux and Standalone Linux

Tags: vmware-server, vmware-player

I have the following setup. 
  I have a Windows XP and Linux system, which are connected to each other directly through cable and not connected to any other network. I have hosted a VMWare with CentOS on XP System. Now I want to assign a static IP to the VMWare, so that I can share the files between the standlone Linux and VMWare CentOS i.e hosted on the XP System.

How can I acheive this setup?

Comment: What VMWare product are you using? VMWare server, Player, Workstation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the VMWare guest configuration, use a bridged mode networking adapter.  In the Linux Guest, assign a static IP in the same network as the two crossover-connected hosts.  You should now have ping connectivity between all hosts.

Once that's done, read up on either using NFS (for linux-to-linux filesharing), or Samba (for everything-to-linux filesharing).

Comment: +1 Nice answer. NFS is the route I went in this situation, with a little tuning and tweaking I managed to get respectable performance from it.